# function parameter breaking JS defaults from EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make a rather basic navigation menu with JS elements (accordion styling).

I seem to have come to a stand still thought as the JS breaks

```js
function subMenu(e) {
  alert(e);
}

function jsDetect() {
  var subs = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-nav');
  for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; ++i) {
    var item = subs[i];
    item.classList.add('hide');
  }
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-link');
  divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(r) {
    r.preventDefault();
    subMenu(el);
  }), false);
}
window.onload = jsDetect;
```

```css
ul.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
}

ul.nav a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

ul.nav,
ul.nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.nav li {
  padding: 0.55em;
}

.main-nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Black', sans-serif;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.sub-nav {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.sub-nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.sub-nav.hide {
  display: none;
}

.sub-nav.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="main-nav" id="home-nav"><a href="home">home</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav" id="articles-nav"><a href="food" class="sub-link">food</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="food/add">add</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="food/list">list</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav" id="articles-nav"><a href="articles" class="sub-link">articles</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="articles/add">add</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="articles/list">list</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav" id="assistance-nav"><a href="assistance">assistance</a></li>
</ul>
```

The above works fine, brings up the alert box which includes the whole url of the link clicked when it contains the class "sub-link"

But what I really need it to do is to let me know the last part of the the url eg "food" or "articles"

I thought by adding a combination of **e.lastIndexOf('/')** and **substr()** to the subMenu function but I'm getting an error of

> e.lastIndexOf is not a function

I'm very confused. All your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: As you don't appear to have that code - `e.lastIndexOf(...)` - in your code it's hard to tell you exactly what's happening, but I'd assume that `e` is not a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last part of the link with

```
console.log(e.getAttribute("href"));
```

see here:

```js
function subMenu(e){
    console.log(e.getAttribute("href"));
}

function jsDetect(){
    var subs = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-nav');
    for(var i = 0; i < subs.length; ++i) {
        var item = subs[i];
        item.classList.add('hide');
    }
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-link');
    divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click',function(r){r.preventDefault();subMenu(el);}),false);
}
window.onload = jsDetect;
```

```css
ul.nav {text-transform: uppercase; background: rgba(0,0,0,1); color: white;}
ul.nav a:link {color: white; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 0.3em;}
ul.nav, ul.nav li {list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
ul.nav li {padding: 0.55em;}
.main-nav {font-weight: bold; border-top: 1px solid white;}
.sub-nav {background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);}
.sub-nav a:hover {background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);}
.sub-nav.hide {display: none;}
.sub-nav.show {display: block}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="main-nav" id="home-nav"><a href="home">home</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav" id="articles-nav"><a href="food" class="sub-link">food</a></li> 
    <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav"><a href="food/add">add</a></li>
    <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav"><a href="food/list">list</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav" id="articles-nav"><a href="articles" class="sub-link">articles</a></li> 
    <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav"><a href="articles/add">add</a></li>
    <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav"><a href="articles/list">list</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav" id="assistance-nav"><a href="assistance">assistance</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are passing the entire element to your subMenu function, so you wouldn't be able to call lastIndexOf or substr on the element itself.
If you ran those methods on a property of the element passed to your subMenu function, then it should work as you expect:

```
alert(e.href.substr(5));
```

or

```
alert(e.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/25n1xbkc/

Answer (score 1):

You can use .pathname to get last part of URL (and replace /):

```
  alert(e.pathname.replace("/",""));
```

[here is good read don't that](https://code-boxx.com/url-parts-javascript/)

[And documentation on web location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

```js
function subMenu(e) {
  alert(e.pathname.replace("/",""));
}

function jsDetect() {
  var subs = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-nav');
  for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; ++i) {
    var item = subs[i];
    item.classList.add('hide');
  }
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-link');
  divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(r) {
    r.preventDefault();
    subMenu(el);
  }), false);
}
window.onload = jsDetect;
```

```css
ul.nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
}

ul.nav a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

ul.nav,
ul.nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.nav li {
  padding: 0.55em;
}

.main-nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Black', sans-serif;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.sub-nav {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.sub-nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.sub-nav.hide {
  display: none;
}

.sub-nav.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="main-nav" id="home-nav"><a href="home">home</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav" id="articles-nav"><a href="food" class="sub-link">food</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="food/add">add</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="food/list">list</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav" id="articles-nav"><a href="articles" class="sub-link">articles</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="articles/add">add</a></li>
  <li class="sub-nav articles-sub-nav hide"><a href="articles/list">list</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav" id="assistance-nav"><a href="assistance">assistance</a></li>
</ul>
```